# Finding missing lines in file

Tags: python, string, list, file, search

I have a 7000+ lines .txt file, containing description and ordered path to image. Example:

```
abnormal /Users/alex/Documents/X-ray-classification/data/images/1.png
abnormal /Users/alex/Documents/X-ray-classification/data/images/2.png
normal /Users/alex/Documents/X-ray-classification/data/images/3.png
normal /Users/alex/Documents/X-ray-classification/data/images/4.png
```

Some lines are missing. I want to somehow automate the search of missing lines. Intuitively i wrote:

```
f = open("data.txt", 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
num = 1
for line in lines:
    if num in line:
        continue
    else:
        print (line)
    num+=1
```

But of course it didn't work, since lines are strings.
Is there any elegant way to sort this out? Using regex maybe?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `str(num)` to do a string comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following should hopefully work - it grabs the number out of the filename, sees if it's more than 1 higher than the previous number, and if so, works out all the 'in-between' numbers and prints them. Printing the number (and then reconstructing the filename later) is needed as `line` will never contain the names of missing files during iteration.

```
# Set this to the first number in the series -1
num = lastnum = 0

with open("data.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Pick the digit out of the filename
        num = int(''.join(x for x in line if x.isdigit()))
        if num - lastnum > 1:
          for i in range(lastnum+1, num):
            print("Missing: {}.png".format(str(i)))
        lastnum = num
```

The main advantage of working this way is that as long as your files are sorted in the list, it can handle starting at numbers other than `1`, and also reports more than one missing number in the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
lines = ["abnormal /Users/alex/Documents/X-ray-classification/data/images/1.png","normal /Users/alex/Documents/X-ray-classification/data/images/3.png","normal /Users/alex/Documents/X-ray-classification/data/images/4.png"]
maxvalue = 4 # or any other maximum value
missing = []
i = 0
for num in range(1, maxvalue+1):
    if str(num) not in lines[i]:
        missing.append(num)
    else:
      i += 1

print(missing)
```

Or if you want to check for the line ending with `XXX.png`:

```
lines = ["abnormal /Users/alex/Documents/X-ray-classification/data/images/1.png","normal /Users/alex/Documents/X-ray-classification/data/images/3.png","normal /Users/alex/Documents/X-ray-classification/data/images/4.png"]
maxvalue = 4 # or any other maximum value
missing = []
i = 0
for num in range(1, maxvalue+1):
    if not lines[i].endswith(str(num) + ".png"):
        missing.append(num)
    else:
      i += 1

print(missing)
```

Example: [here](https://repl.it/repls/DroopyInsubstantialHammerheadbird)

Comment: Thanks, but there are errors in both versions: TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable in line 5

Comment: @AlexNikitin Thanks for reporting it, fixed it, should work now